# Bitshifting a byte buffer

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a buffer of binary data:

```
SInt16 *buffer = (SInt16 *)calloc(1024,sizeof(SInt16));
```

I want to process a chunk of data off the front of this buffer (for example 50 data points)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50 ; ++i){
   process_data(buffer[i])
}
```

Once the data is processed I don't need it any more, so I want to discard it and place my pointer *buffer at the 51st data point. However, I still need  buffer to point to a buffer that has 1024 places in it. To do this I thought I would do a bit shift to do this because it accomplishes my goal and, to my knowledge, is quick (I'm in a high priority thread). However I'm unclear how bit shifting works with byte arrays.

**First, if I want to shift the array such that *buffer points to the value formerly contained in buffer[50], is that a left or a right shift in C (Objective C)?**

**Second, if I shift buffer will it shift all 1024 data points or will it only shift one SInt16 datapoint at buffer[0]?**

The idea here is that a processor will read chunks off the beginning of the buffer and then signal a file reader on another thread to append new data to the end of buffer. If 50 data points are processed, then those 50 points are discarded, and the file reader appends 50 new points of data to the end of the byte buffer.

Comment: Bit shifting has nothing to do with arrays / buffers. You should think about using/implementing a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for this. (Decided to add this as answer)

Comment: Bit-shifting is implemented at the processor level I believe . So I would assume it works on a word (32-bit or 64-bit) at a time. Shifting an array left or right has nothing to do with bit-shifting (its more like shifting whole a bunch of contiguous bytes left or right).
And I think there's no constant-time solution for this problem; it will be at least (sizeof(array) - 50)...

Comment: @mtahmed - which is *exactly* why you use a circular buffer in these situations; there's no reason to relocate data in the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit shifting has nothing to do with arrays / buffers.

You *could* move the data around in the buffer via copying, but that's incredibly inefficient.

You really should think about using/implementing a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for this.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with bitshift. You need shift of integral size (in term of bytes). You may use `memmove` or equivalent.

OTOH you definitely have a flaw in your design. Shifting your data takes time proportional to its remaining part. So, if you processed only 50 first elements, and then moving 1024-50 remaining ones - it's ineffective.

You'd better redesign your code so that you move just pointer, still you have (in another variable) the pointer to the beginning of the allocation

Answer (score 1):

This sounds suspiciously like the standard use case for a circular buffer.

If so, you'd be keeping a read and write location along with the main storage: you just update the write location to indicate the elements you consumed are free to be overwritten.

Note that it is only circular because you wrap around at the end, the underlying storage doesn't have to change.

Take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for details.

---

Note that you'd be copying (eg, memcpy or memmove) here, bitshifting is usually done *inside* machine words, not between them. As valdo says, the pointer manipulation is much faster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is not operator to shift whole array in one statement. Even if you manage something like this (for example, crate union that contain `SInt64` and `SInt16[4]`), Your program will not portable (since the endian is different on different machines).

I suggest you to have `int begin,end;` to save the indexes of the data, and use the `%` operator.